# Android: Unable to convert string to JsonArray

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have a json which is getting returned as array but I'm unable to convert it into a list. The string looks like:

```
"[{\"@context\":[\"v1\"],\"id\":\"did\",\"type\":[\"VerifiableCredential\"],\"issuer\":\"did\",\"issuanceDate\":\"2022-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"expirationDate\":\"2023-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"credentialSchema\":{\"id\":\"didversion=0.2\",\"type\":\"JsonSchemaValidator2018\"},\"credentialSubject\":{\"contact\":\"support@abccompany.com\",\"name\":\"Fedex\",\"orgId\":\"fedex\",\"privacyPolicy\":\"privacy-policy\",\"services\":[{\"purposes\":[{\"purpose\":\"To get my Health Insights data into my wallet.\"}],\"service\":\"download\"}],\"technical\":{\"download\":{\"id\":\"DOQQ163002\",\"linkId\":\"c97b8411-a6ba-4955-88e7-071353fbc2b8\",\"passcode\":\"2a57c0cd-b036-4c6f-9a41-adde8be8cc3e\",\"url\":\"attachments\"},\"symmetricKey\":{\"algorithm\":\"aes-256-cbc\",\"iv\":\"8qbl7cgPpuVzGrUSmt/Vsw==\",\"value\":\"3ROXMpHAEO8FNSVMzkTZIjnbFE7lD4T1FgwWs3B83JA=\"}},\"type\":\"profile\",\"userAgreement\":\"By agreeing to create this connection, I give Merative permission to request my data from Health Insights, credentialize it, and send it to my digital wallet.\",\"website\":\"com/\"},\"proof\":{\"created\":\"2022-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"creator\":\"did\",\"nonce\":\"c6cd9a75-e8d2-468d-8305-427667ea778f\",\"signatureValue\":\"MEQCIAQd94Q4zE7OXLYdpWUW_eMBBtPBLEQGJ4DK8uNIJMxgAiBA3FGtmy67qwcpVyAdx3GqCa2X7LoCa5StR4G_EpIYRg\",\"type\":\"EcdsaSecp256r1Signature2019\"}},{\"@context\":[\"v1\"],\"id\":\"did\",\"type\":[\"VerifiableCredential\",\"ID\"],\"issuer\":\"did\",\"issuanceDate\":\"2022-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"expirationDate\":\"2023-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"credentialSchema\":{\"id\":\"did;version=0.2\",\"type\":\"JsonSchemaValidator2018\"},\"credentialSubject\":{\"birthDate\":\"1965-02-05\",\"email\":\"anshul.tyagi@abc.com\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"id\":\"DOQQ163002\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"Ireson\",\"givenName\":\"Davian\"},\"organization\":\"fedex\",\"ssn\":\"123456789\",\"type\":\"id\"},\"proof\":{\"created\":\"2022-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"creator\":\"did\",\"nonce\":\"19766c23-5826-4226-98b3-8680db73cd09\",\"signatureValue\":\"MEUCIBdmLk3Xh\",\"type\":\"EcdsaSecp256r1Signature2019\"}}]"
```

I have tried following approach but it's not working for me.

```
val myModelList: List<Model> = gson.fromJson(s.toJsonElement(), mutableListOf<Model>().javaClass)
```

Can anyone please let me know how I can convert this string to Json and then into List?

Answer (score 1):

The returned json format seems to be incorrect.
[image: Photo 1]

Comment: But that can be fixed by `.replace("\\\"", "\"")`

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple is kotlin, No need to replace anything : Follow mentioned code :

```
val t = "[{\"@context\":[\"v1\"],\"id\":\"did\",\"type\":[\"VerifiableCredential\"],\"issuer\":\"did\",\"issuanceDate\":\"2022-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"expirationDate\":\"2023-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"credentialSchema\":{\"id\":\"didversion=0.2\",\"type\":\"JsonSchemaValidator2018\"},\"credentialSubject\":{\"contact\":\"support@abccompany.com\",\"name\":\"Fedex\",\"orgId\":\"fedex\",\"privacyPolicy\":\"privacy-policy\",\"services\":[{\"purposes\":[{\"purpose\":\"To get my Health Insights data into my wallet.\"}],\"service\":\"download\"}],\"technical\":{\"download\":{\"id\":\"DOQQ163002\",\"linkId\":\"c97b8411-a6ba-4955-88e7-071353fbc2b8\",\"passcode\":\"2a57c0cd-b036-4c6f-9a41-adde8be8cc3e\",\"url\":\"attachments\"},\"symmetricKey\":{\"algorithm\":\"aes-256-cbc\",\"iv\":\"8qbl7cgPpuVzGrUSmt/Vsw==\",\"value\":\"3ROXMpHAEO8FNSVMzkTZIjnbFE7lD4T1FgwWs3B83JA=\"}},\"type\":\"profile\",\"userAgreement\":\"By agreeing to create this connection, I give Merative permission to request my data from Health Insights, credentialize it, and send it to my digital wallet.\",\"website\":\"com/\"},\"proof\":{\"created\":\"2022-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"creator\":\"did\",\"nonce\":\"c6cd9a75-e8d2-468d-8305-427667ea778f\",\"signatureValue\":\"MEQCIAQd94Q4zE7OXLYdpWUW_eMBBtPBLEQGJ4DK8uNIJMxgAiBA3FGtmy67qwcpVyAdx3GqCa2X7LoCa5StR4G_EpIYRg\",\"type\":\"EcdsaSecp256r1Signature2019\"}},{\"@context\":[\"v1\"],\"id\":\"did\",\"type\":[\"VerifiableCredential\",\"ID\"],\"issuer\":\"did\",\"issuanceDate\":\"2022-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"expirationDate\":\"2023-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"credentialSchema\":{\"id\":\"did;version=0.2\",\"type\":\"JsonSchemaValidator2018\"},\"credentialSubject\":{\"birthDate\":\"1965-02-05\",\"email\":\"anshul.tyagi@abc.com\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"id\":\"DOQQ163002\",\"name\":{\"familyName\":\"Ireson\",\"givenName\":\"Davian\"},\"organization\":\"fedex\",\"ssn\":\"123456789\",\"type\":\"id\"},\"proof\":{\"created\":\"2022-07-27T10:24:48Z\",\"creator\":\"did\",\"nonce\":\"19766c23-5826-4226-98b3-8680db73cd09\",\"signatureValue\":\"MEUCIBdmLk3Xh\",\"type\":\"EcdsaSecp256r1Signature2019\"}}]";
val a = JSONArray(t)
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: KISHAN  : $a")
```

[image: Image From Android Studio]

[image: Converted JSON]

Comment: I forgot to mention that my string is having `semicolon separated strings` also. Any idea for that also?

Comment: I have copied the string you mentioned above. if you have another string you can edit your question @AnshulTyagi

Comment: It's a static string so it'll work fine. I'm printing the string and it prints with double quotes. Like `"[.....]"`. That throws `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING`

Comment: if you mention an example of your string, i think it will be more better for me to understand rather than we are just assume.